# List of lists to array conversion. Mixed strings and floats

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have an array (150,40) that looks like:

```
list_of_lists= ['name_1' 0.0123
        'name_2' 0.1234
   ... 'name_40' 0.213241
Name: 2015-03-26 16:02:42.117000, dtype: float64,

and so on, 149 more ]
```

I have two questions:

The 40 names are all the same for all 150 lists, how can I convert these to the columns of an array, and the values (whcih differ across all 150 lists) to rows corresponding to each column name ?
Example:

```
array= [ 'name_1', 'name_2',... 'name_40
          0.0123,    0.1234,     0.213241]
```

Second, the `Name: 2015-03-26 16:02:42.117000` is actually a timestamp, and I would need this to be the 0 column, with 150 rows
like:

```
array= [ 'timestamp'     'name_1', 'name_2',... 'name_40
        16:02:42.117000   0.0123,    0.1234,     0.213241]
```

I have no clue why the timestamp is the Name of the list in the first place
And I have no idea how to convert this to an array for further processing

Answer (score 0):

In regards the first question, one way you could do this, strictly using only `numpy` would be to create a new `numpy` structured array and create a set of two for each loops (`for x in list`), the top level to loop over array then the nested one to loop over each array element, appending it to the new structured array. That being said this approach will result in code that has poor readability and overly complicated.

A better option is to use a `pandas` DataFrame. You should be able to convert all your `numpy` structured arrays directly into pandas as simply as this `pandas.DataFrame(mylist)` or read in the data directly into a dataframe if you're reading it in from external files.

The approach below is starting from your structured arrays (but you could just swap `pd.DataFrame` to something like `pd.read_csv(...)` if using csv files or another function for other file formats.

```
import pandas as pd

# need a list of those arrays to allow easy looping
listofArrays = [array1, array2, ...] 

# now using list comprehension, converting all those to dataframes
listofDataFrames = [pd.DataFrame(arrayX) for arrayX in listofArrays]

# now we can just use pd.Concat to put all those together
completeSet = pd.concat(listofDataFrames)
```

And with that you have a dataframe with everything pulled together. Which if you strictly need it, can be converted back to a purely `numpy` data structure.

---

In regards to the second question, this can be solved using regular expression, or since its a fairly simple string, using `split` and `join`.

Its not clear on what your input data format, but if I'm reading correctly this is not in an array yet. So I take it the input looks something like

```
name: date1 timestamp       data: 213123 12313
name2: date2 timestamp2     data: 21311223 313
```

Even if it is different, the same principle applies.

Since this is relatively simple, `split` and `join` would be the easiest approach

```
originalnamestring = "Name: 2015-03-26 16:02:42.117000"

splitbyspace = originalnamestring.split(" ")

name = splitbyspace[0]

# and if you want to remove the : at end
name = name[:-1]

# if you want separate date and time

date = splitbyspace[1]
time = splitbyspace[2]

# or combined timestamp

timestamp = " ".join(splitbyspace[1:])
```

Comment: Thanks!.... Alright so the pd and pd contact make a dataframe, but the timestamps are the column names (I need them to be the rows), AND, I get a bunch of NaN (which is odd because a lot of values are small numbers )

Comment: So are the arrays the primary data source (say is there a text file you used parsed to create those arrays or are the arrays the start point)? If its a text file, it would be the easiest to separate the name/timestamp there.

Comment: Also in regards to the NaN, what does that data value look like on the array? NaN would imply the something is missing. Pandas essentially uses numpy as a backend for handling its data types so anything in anumpy array, should be 100% compatible with a pandas Dataframe.

Comment: Interesting. So, there is a huge dataframe, and I am extracting some values, which results in my list of lists (type: list ) using array = [] and a for loop to extract the section im interested in and then using array.apend(whatever I need )
The data is just.. numbers: anywhere from small decimals to positive numbers

Comment: So, I can transpose the dataframe and that fixes it, but what do I do with my NaNs